# Common practice for authentification in AngularJS + Sails SPA

Tags: angularjs, authentication, sails.js

I make a single page application with Sails and AngularJS. And now i'm trying to make an authentication.

I have this angular code on client side:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl:'pages/postList.html',
            controller:'PostListController'
        }).
        when('/createPost', {
            templateUrl:'pages/postCreation.html',
            controller:'PostCreationController'
        })
}])
```

Here all *.html* files are stored at *assets/* folder, which is public. But i don't want to have a public access to *postCreation.html*, i want to permit access to this file for some users using policies.

I think i can put all *.html* files in views folder, create a controller methods for each file and than use policies. But i'm not sure this is a good solution.

So, how to use policies in Sails + Angular SPA?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use sails policies for this. Instead, you can use the `resolve` parameter in your `$routeProvider`.

From [$routeProvider docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

> An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired.

I have something along the likes of following configured in an app of mine, which is working great (using `$stateProvider`, but the concept should work just as well for `$routeProvider`):

```
.state('stateOnlyCertainUsersCanSee', {
  url: "/stateOnlyCertainUsersCanSee",
  templateUrl: "myTemplate.html",
  controller: 'myController',
  resolve: {
    validate: function($q, $sails, $state) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $sails.get("/me") // gets user info
          .then(
          function(response) {
            if (response.user.canAccessThisPage) { // Condition on which to pass or fail an user
              defer.resolve();
            }
            else {
              defer.reject("No access to page");
              $state.go("home"); // Redirect wherever you want
            }
          }
      );
      return defer.promise;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you please comment my solution, which i explained in the end of the question (creating a controller for each of the page)? Whether it has disadvantages?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even possible to do what you're thinking of, and even if it is, it seems unnecessarily complex. As for efficiency loading the .html file, we're talking about a few KBs, which really isn't a problem in any realistic case.

Comment: And in this case user can change the code, so he will have access to the _.html_ page. Yes, it's just plain html page, but i think it can be useful for huckers in some cases, isn't it?